rhythmbox not listening on port 3689
DAAP plugin is enabled and set to share my music.
I have enabled DAAP plugin in Rhythmbox, ticked the "Share my music" option, but rhythmbox is not listening on port 3689.
netstat -tulpn doesn't show 3689.
nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-12-08 01:34 CET

Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)  

Host is up (0.0000030s latency).

Not shown: 992 closed tcp ports (reset)

PORT     STATE SERVICE

22/tcp   open  ssh

80/tcp   open  http

111/tcp  open  rpcbind

139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn

445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds

631/tcp  open  ipp

2049/tcp open  nfs

3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds

